# How to import localstorage data on axios create

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a component inside React for handling URL calls, it simply has a baseurl and headers I use everywhere in my application.

The problem is when there is no data in localStorage I get an error and the whole application stops.

If I use if condition I can't export inside it because export has to be at the top level.

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://www.homrz.com/re_homrz/api/admin/`,
  // headers: {
  //   Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token}`,
  //   "Content-Type": "application/json",
  // },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may help

```
 import axios from "axios";
 
  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token

  export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://www.homrz.com/re_homrz/api/admin/`,
  headers: {
     Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` ? null,
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one file auth-header.js with below code

```
export function authHeader() {
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    
    if (user !== null && user !== "" && user !== undefined) {
        return {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.token
        };
    } else {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        };
    }
}
```

Then use it like below,

```
import axios from "axios";
import { authHeader } from './auth-header';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://www.homrz.com/re_homrz/api/admin/',
  headers: authHeader(),
});
```